# seaborn.objects: How can I put text in italics?

Tags: seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

When making a graph with seaborn objects, how can I put text in specific places in the graph in italics?

For example, given the code below, how can I put the variable names in the figure legend and x-axis in italics? Specifically, I want "male" and "female" in the figure legend and "First", "Second", and "Third" in the x-axis in italics.

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
(
    so.Plot(titanic, x='class', color='sex').add(so.Bar(), so.Count(), so.Stack())
)
```

Thank you.